# Linking Different Tables Into a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Ive got the below SQL query that calculates Qty and Values by months and then places them into 24 columns  so the data looks like this:

```
Jan , JanQty, Feb  , FebQTY, Mar , MarQty 
1285,   35  , 3228 ,   36  , 1750,   18
```

But now I want to add in fields like Business Partners(OINV & ORIN) and Items(INV1 & RIN1) so that the data has more row for the items/business partners going down from different table so it looks like this:

```
Business Partner, Items   , Jan, JanQty, Feb  , FebQTY, Mar, MarQty
SAP Ltd         , Software, 150, 1     , 0    , 0     , 500, 2 
SAP Ltd         , Phones  , 175, 4     , 145  , 1     , 100, 1
SAP Ltd         , Tablets , 10 , 9     , 86   , 8     , 400, 3 
JPC Ltd         , Software, 350, 7     , 999  , 9     , 250, 4 
JPC Ltd         , PC's    , 350, 7     , 999  , 9     , 250, 4
JPC Ltd         , Software, 350, 7     , 999  , 9     , 250, 4
```

Ive tried a number of different way but cannot get it to work, any help would be great.

Below is my query

```
SELECT 
        Jan, 
        JanQty,
        Feb,
        FebQty
        Mar,
        MarQty,
        Apr,
        AprQty,
        May,
        MayQty,
        June,
        JuneQty,
        July,
        JulyQty,
        Aug,
        AugQty,
        Sept,
        SeptQty,
        Oct,
        OctQty,
        Nov,
        NovQty,
        Dec,
        DecQty
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT
            SUM(JanQty) as 'JanQty',
            SUM(FebQty) as 'FebQty',
            SUM(MarQty) as 'MarQty',
            SUM(AprQty) as 'AprQty',
            SUM(MayQty) as 'MayQty',
            SUM(JuneQty) as 'JuneQty',
            SUM(JulyQty) as 'JulyQty',
            SUM(AugQty) as 'AugQty',
            SUM(SeptQty) as 'SeptQty',
            SUM(OctQty) as 'OctQty',
            SUM(NovQty) as 'NovQty',
            SUM(DecQty) as 'DecQty'
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT
                ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
                ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
                ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty,
                ISNULL([4],0) as AprQty,
                ISNULL([5],0) as MayQty,
                ISNULL([6],0) as JuneQty,
                ISNULL([7],0) as JulyQty,
                ISNULL([8],0) as AugQty,
                ISNULL([9],0) as SeptQty,
                ISNULL([10],0) as OctQty,
                ISNULL([11],0) as NovQty,
                ISNULL([12],0) as DecQty
            FROM 
              (
                SELECT 
                    SUM(T0.Quantity) as QtyBal,
                    MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
                FROM 
                    INV1 T0
                     inner join 
                    OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
                WHERE 
                    t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                    year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
                GROUP BY t0.Quantity, t1.DocDate
              ) s

                PIVOT 
                  (
                    SUM(QtyBal) FOR 
                    Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
                  ) p

                UNION ALL

                SELECT
                    ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
                    ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
                    ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty,
                    ISNULL([4],0) as AprQty,
                    ISNULL([5],0) as MayQty,
                    ISNULL([6],0) as JuneQty,
                    ISNULL([7],0) as JulyQty,
                    ISNULL([8],0) as AugQty,
                    ISNULL([9],0) as SeptQty,
                    ISNULL([10],0) as OctQty,
                    ISNULL([11],0) as NovQty,
                    ISNULL([12],0) as DecQty
                from
                  (
                    select 
                        SUM((case when T0.NoInvtryMv = 'Y' then t0.Quantity else -t0.Quantity end)) as QtyBal,
                        MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
                    from 
                        RIN1 T0
                         inner join 
                        ORIN T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
                    where 
                        t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                        year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
                    group by t1.DocDate) s

                    Pivot
                      (
                        SUM(QtyBal) FOR 
                        Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
                      ) p
              ) sqa
          ) qty
             CROSS JOIN 
          (
            SELECT
                SUM(Jan) as 'Jan',
                SUM(Feb) as 'Feb',
                SUM(Mar) as 'Mar',
                SUM(Apr) as 'Apr',
                SUM(May) as 'May',
                SUM(June) as 'June',
                SUM(July) as 'July',
                SUM(Aug) as 'Aug',
                SUM(Sept) as 'Sept',
                SUM(oct) as 'Oct',
                SUM(nov) as 'Nov',
                SUM(Dec) as 'Dec'
            FROM
              (
                SELECT
                    ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
                    ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
                    ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
                    ISNULL([4],0) as Apr,
                    ISNULL([5],0) as May,
                    ISNULL([6],0) as June,
                    ISNULL([7],0) as July,
                    ISNULL([8],0) as Aug,
                    ISNULL([9],0) as Sept,
                    ISNULL([10],0) as Oct,
                    ISNULL([11],0) as Nov,
                    ISNULL([12],0) as Dec
                FROM
                  (
                    SELECT 
                        SUM(T0.LineTotal) as Bal,
                        MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
                    FROM 
                        INV1 T0
                         inner join 
                        OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
                    WHERE 
                        t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                        year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
                    GROUP BY t0.LineTotal, t1.DocDate
                  ) s

                PIVOT 
                  (
                    SUM(Bal) FOR 
                    Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
                  ) p

                UNION ALL 

                SELECT
                    ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
                    ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
                    ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
                    ISNULL([4],0) as Apr,
                    ISNULL([5],0) as May,
                    ISNULL([6],0) as June,
                    ISNULL([7],0) as July,
                    ISNULL([8],0) as Aug,
                    ISNULL([9],0) as Sept,
                    ISNULL([10],0) as Oct,
                    ISNULL([11],0) as Nov,
                    ISNULL([12],0) as Dec
                from
                  (
                    select 
                        SUM(-T0.LineTotal) as Bal,
                        MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
                    from 
                        RIN1 T0
                         inner join 
                        ORIN T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
                    where 
                        t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                        year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
                    group by -t0.LineTotal, t1.DocDate
                  ) s

                Pivot
                  (
                    SUM(Bal) FOR 
                    Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
                  ) p
              ) sqb
          ) Bal
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the 2 additional fields are already part of your base tables?  In that case you would add them as a group by at the lowest level of your nested queries e.g.

```
 SELECT             Business_Partner, 
                    Items,
                    ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
                    ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
                    ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
```

Flow that group by up to where you pivot your data.  Then you include the new fields as non-pivoted columns.

It's something like this:

```
SELECT
            Business_Partner,
            Items,
            ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
            ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
            ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty
          FROM
          (SELECT 
                Business_Partner,
                Items,
                SUM(T0.Quantity) as QtyBal,
                MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
            FROM 
                INV1 T0
                 inner join 
                OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
            WHERE 
                t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
            GROUP BY t0.Quantity, t1.DocDate)
```

Comment: Yes the field are from the base table. The fields I need to add are: T1.Cardname, T0.ItemCode 

Ive made the above changes in a small section of the query just to test, but i just get the error "The multi-part identifier "FEILD NAME" could not be bound"

Comment: I don't see Feild name in the code you provided.  That error sounds like you've got a join or something in your select that doesn't exist e.g. is it a typo and you want 'Field Name'?  Also I'd suggest running smaller chunks of your code to make sure they work and then expanding the bits you run.  This will make it easier to pinpoint the errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the future it'll be much easier to answer if you provide some test data and the schema you're working with.

With that said, below is a sample of how I'd go about it. If you're pulling data from multiple tables then I'd suggest pulling the data you need from the separate tables and then wrapping a select similar to the one below around the query that gets all the data. I'd avoid the pivoting if possible as I think it's overly complicated if you already know there will be static columns (monthamount/monthquantity in this case).

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    BusinessPartner VARCHAR(15),
    Item VARCHAR(25),
    Price INT,
    [MONTH] int
)

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 'SAP', 'Software', 44, 1
UNION
SELECT 'SAP', 'Software', 51, 1
UNION
SELECT 'SAP', 'Software', 115, 2
UNION
SELECT 'SAP', 'Phones', 11, 1
UNION
SELECT 'JDC', 'Software', 21, 1
UNION
SELECT 'JDC', 'Software', 21345, 2
UNION
SELECT 'JDC', 'Software', 2346, 2
UNION
SELECT 'JDC', 'Phones', 1123, 1
UNION
SELECT 'JDC', 'Phones', 5415, 1

SELECT BusinessPartner, 
    Item, 
    Jan = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN Price ELSE 0 END),
    JanQty = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Feb = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN Price ELSE 0 END),
    FebQty = SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM #Test
    GROUP BY BusinessPartner, Item
    ORDER BY BusinessPartner, Item
```